# How do I get jekyll to run without server?

Tags: html, jekyll

In order for me to view the site, it looks like I need to run `bundle exec jekyll serve` and open the server address in my web browser.

How do I go about having the viewing the site without running the command. I've went into the `_site` and clicked on the `index.html` file without running the server and noticed this.

Do you have any suggestions on how to go about this? There is no styling and none of the links works.

[image]

Is it possible to just place the `.md` file in posts folder and be able to view it without having to run a server still styled?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The link to your CSS file is probably an absolute URL (e.g. `/css/main.css`), and that won't make sense when you open the HTML file directly. You could workaround this by injecting the CSS into the page or using a relative URL, but this is not the only issue you will face trying to avoid a local web server. Unless you have a good reason to do so, you should use one.

Comment: @Ross - Changing the base url under `_config.yml` seems to work in directing to the correct files but I am still encountering issues with the title link. I'm not sure if this is the best method to take to resolving this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your static files using `bundle exec jekyll build`, then all your files will be in `_site`.

Now you need a server to serve theses static files. You can install something like `nginx` or `apache`.

Once it's done you'll want to copy your static files that are inside `_site` under `/var/www/html/` and make sure your server is started with a command like:

```
sudo service nginx start
```

Comment: The thing is I'm not interested in using a server to serve these files. I want to be able to build the files and open them within index.html. From what I can see, unless I manually change the paths to "_site/../assets/main.css", it won't work as the default is "/assets/main.css". How do I correct these paths automatically so they are directing to the correct locations?

Comment: From what I can see, changing the base url under `_config.yml` seems to help but I'm still encountering issues regarding the title link directing to a folder instead of the index file.